# How to check if user already selected an item inside QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qmodelindex

I want to be able to differentiate whether a user selected an item of my QListWidget, because he may also have entered a free text instead.
I tried by checking the currentIndex of the QListWidget, but it seems like the currentIndex function does not return None as I have been hoping. Is there an easy way or may I need to implement a onSelectionChanged method to know whether user selected an item? If I have to go the "method implementation" way, how could the user "unselect" his selection?

```
    def ok_clicked(self):
    self.sig_1_index = self.dialog_layout.data_series_sig_list_1.currentIndex()
    self.sig_2_index = self.dialog_layout.data_series_sig_list_2.currentIndex()
    self.text_2 = self.dialog_layout.data_series_operator.currentText()
    if self.sig_1_index != None: #doesnt work
        if self.sig_2_index != -1: #also doesnt work
            self.text_1 = self.dialog_layout.data_series_sig_list_1.itemFromIndex(self.sig_1_index).text()
            self.text_3 = self.dialog_layout.data_series_sig_list_2.itemFromIndex(self.sig_2_index).text()
        else:
            self.text_1 = self.dialog_layout.data_series_filter_1.toPlainText()
            self.text_3 = self.dialog_layout.data_series_sig_list_2.itemFromIndex(self.sig_2_index).text()
    else:
        if self.sig_2_index != None:
            self.text_1 = self.dialog_layout.data_series_sig_list_1.itemFromIndex(self.sig_1_index).text()
            self.text_3 = self.dialog_layout.data_series_filter_2.toPlainText()
        else:
            self.text_1 = self.dialog_layout.data_series_filter_1.toPlainText()
            self.text_3 = self.dialog_layout.data_series_filter_2.toPlainText()
    print(self.text_1 + self.text_2 + self.text_3)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "entered a free text instead".

Comment: User can either enter Text Into a textfield or select one item in the List

Comment: So, you want to check if the "text field" has something written in it, otherwise use the selected item of the list widget? Please try to be more clear in what you're asking. Also, be aware that item views always return a valid QModelIndex with `currentIndex()` (assuming at least an item exists), even when no item is selected, so you should use `selectedIndexes()` (or `selectedItems()` for QListWidget). Finally, if you need a text field with single line input (not multiple lines), use QLineEdit, not QTextEdit.